# Most efficient way to replace long list of tokens in a long list of documents/ sentences

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to find the most efficient way to replace a long list (10,000) of non-hyphenated tokens (e.g. world class) with their respective hyphenated forms (e.g. world-class).

The issue I am facing is that I have to do the operation over a large number of documents/ sentences (500,000).

This is my current code:

```
# build dict of tokens to replace # {first class: first-class, ... }
with open(file_with_tokens, 'rb') as f:
    tokens = {k.replace('-', ' ').lower(): k for k in f}

# sort dictionary to make sure longer tokens are replaced first
tokens_sorted = sorted(tokens, key=len, reverse=True)

# compile
tokens_escaped = ['\\b' + re.escape(replacement) + '\\b' for replacement in tokens_sorted]
pattern_re = re.compile(r'(?:%s)' % '|'.join(tokens_escaped), re.IGNORECASE)

# loop list of sentences, replace tokens and output
output = []
for sent in open(fsents, 'rb'):
    sent_new = pattern_re.sub(lambda match: tokens[match.group(0).lower()], sent)
    if sent_new != sent:
        output.append(sent_new)

return output
```

The above approach takes around 12 hours to complete. Any suggestion on how to speed up the process?

EDIT FOR THE SOLUTION IMPLEMENTED

I ended up updating my function as follows:

```
...

# loop list of sentences, replace tokens and output
pool = Pool(4)
output = pool.map(replace_token, itertools.repeat(pattern_re), itertools.repeat(tokens), sents))
return output
```

The function replace_token being defined as follows:

```
def replace_token(pattern_re, tokens, sent):
    return pattern_re.sub(lambda match: tokens[match.group(0).lower()], sent)
```

Comment: Multithreading would help speed it up

Comment: Thanks Cricket_007. Any suggestion on how to that? I am not familiar with multithreading.

Comment: go to this link on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WaXK8G1hb_Q&index=34&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAcbMi1sH6oAMk4JHw91mC_) and watch the tutorial its quick and to the point

Comment: Joe, the video was helpful and multithreading was the way to go. On a quick test on 10,000 sentences, I could reduce the time from 28min to 5min. Many thanks

Comment: You can answer your own questions below rather than updating the question.